# How does $\frac d{ds}(Y(s) \cdot s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}) =s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}} (Y' - \frac{s^2-6}{2s}\cdot Y)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This arises when solving the differential equation Solve $Y' - \frac{s^2-6}{2s}Y=-\frac1{2x^2}$

The integrating factor turns out to be $s^3e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}$, and then we multiply the equation above by the integrating factor and replace the left hand side using the equation below.

$$\frac d{ds}(Y(s) \cdot s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}) =s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}} (Y' - \frac{s^2-6}{2s}\cdot Y)$$

What I don't understand is the derivation there, it doesn't seem correct.

$\frac d{ds}(Y(s) \cdot s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}) =Y' \cdot s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}} + Y\cdot \frac d{ds}(s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}})$

The above two equations together imply that $\frac d{ds} (s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}) = -\frac{s^2-6}{2s}$, which is not correct? Because $\frac d{ds} (s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}})= e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}(3s^2-\frac {s^4}{2})?$

Comment: Did the answer resolve your issues?

Answer (score 1):

By the product/chain rule, we have

$$\dfrac{d}{ds} (u(s) v(s) w(s)) = u'(s) v(s) w(s) + v'(s) u(s) w(s) + w'(s) u(s) v(s)$$

Working that out, we have

$$\frac d{ds}(Y(s) \cdot s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}}) =s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}} (Y' - \frac{s^2-6}{2s}\cdot Y)$$

The way you wrote is okay too, but for that last item, we have to apply the product rule again. That is, you have to apply the chain rule again because you have a product of two terms here

$$...+ Y\cdot \frac d{ds}(s^3 e^{\frac{-s^2}{4}})$$